# 3 Javascript counters on same page

Tags: javascript

**Hi. I have an issue.**

I just got an Exam in making a webpage for my media classes.
This is an attitude campaign for the Norwegian governmental department called "Helsedirektoratet"

So the issue is that it won't show me all three counters at the same time.
So if anyone could help me that would be great!

(First time using Javascript)

```html
<div id="seconds-counter"> </div>
<script>
  var seconds = 0;
  var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

  function incrementSeconds() {
    seconds += 1;
    el.innerText = "Du har vært sukkerfri " + seconds + " sekunder.";
  }

  var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
</script>
<div id="seconds-counter"> </div>
<script>
  var seconds = 3;
  var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

  function incrementSeconds() {
    seconds += 2;
    el.innerText = "Du har også spart " + seconds + " kroner.";
  }
  var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
</script>
<div id="seconds-counter"> </div>
<script>
  var seconds = 1;
  var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

  function incrementSeconds() {
    seconds += 0.5;
    el.innerText = "Du har også spart " + seconds + " kalorier.";
  }
  var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: use different variable names for each one.

Comment: ids are meant to be unique. Try changing the ids to seconds-counter1, seconds-counter2, seconds-counter3

Answer (score 0):

You need to change de DIV IDs, example:

```
<div id="seconds-counter"> </div>
<script>
  var seconds = 0;
  var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

  function incrementSeconds() {
    seconds += 1;
    el.innerText = "Du har vært sukkerfri " + seconds + " sekunder.";
  }

  var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
</script>
<div id="seconds-counter-kroner"> </div>
<script>
  var seconds = 3;
  var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

  function incrementSeconds() {
    seconds += 2;
    el.innerText = "Du har også spart " + seconds + " kroner.";
  }
  var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
</script>
<div id="seconds-counter-kalorier"> </div>
<script>
  var seconds = 1;
  var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

  function incrementSeconds() {
    seconds += 0.5;
    el.innerText = "Du har også spart " + seconds + " kalorier.";
  }
  var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
</script>
```

Doing this you avoid the override.

Comment: Don't forget change the name in the document.getElementById('The name of your div')

Answer (score 0):

You might want to wrap the code into a function to create the timers. Through that you shorten your code, and you can enclosure the variables so that you got different values for all the different timers:

```
function createTimer(message, selector) {
  var seconds = 0;
  var el = document.getElementById(selector);

  function incrementSeconds() {
     seconds += 1;
     el.innerText = message + seconds + " sekunder.";
   }

   setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
}
```

So you can just do:

```
createTimer("Du har vært sukkerfri ", "seconds-counter");
createTimer("Something else ", "seconds-counter2");
```

PS: Ids inside the DOM should be unique.